# How to send NSData using NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, nskeyedarchiver

Hello everyone, 
               I want to send data using `[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myDictionary]`. In my dictionary I have an Array. This Array contains the dictionary. Now when I send this dictionary, I am only getting the key without any array objects.
Here it is my code:

Sending:`NSMutableDictionary *infoDictionary =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
 [infoDictionary setObject:collectedSongs forKey:@"library"];
 [self sendData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[infoDictionary copy]]];`

Receiving:`NSDictionary *info = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];`

Now info doesn't contain any array.

Comment: "In my dictionary I have an Array. This Array contains the dictionary"?  Err what?

Comment: @trojanfoe thanks for prompt reply. Problem is whenever I am receiving it in my other class there is no array in my dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSMutableDictionary *info1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
info1[@"arr"] = sendArray ;
[self sendData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[info1 copy]]];
```

Worked for me.